# Extend user data on OAuth login in Next Auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to get this data in my index.js to use. I am using promise to extend the info from my DB users like this:

```
Providers.Google({
  clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,

  async profile(profile, tokens) {

    //setup query values
    let qv = profile;

    let userLookup = await query(
      prepare`SELECT * FROM users WHERE Nickname = 'Test' LIMIT 1`
    );

    if (!Object.keys(userLookup.data).length) {
      if (process.env.DEBUG >= 1) {
        console.log("[DEBUG] Sign In: User couldn't be found");
      }
      return Promise.reject(
        new Error(
          "We couldn't find your account, please check your email address and password and try again"
        )
      );
    }

    //de-nest the user data
    userLookup = userLookup.data[0];

    console.log(userLookup);

    return {
      id: profile.id,
      name: userLookup.Nickname,
      email: profile.email,
      image: profile.picture,
    };
  },
```

and in my index I am just using the template example.

```
<div>
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {session && (
        <>
          <p>Welcome, {session.user.name}</p>
          <br />
          <img src={session.user.image} alt="" />
        </>
      )}
      {!session && (
        <>
          <p>Please Sign in</p>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
```

How can I access the `name: userLookup.Nickname,` from above or even extend it like this.

```
return {
      id: profile.id,
      anotherVariable: userLookup.anotherVariable
    };
```

THanks.
Just don't know where it returns or how to access it.

Comment: where is this profile function in callbacks? https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks

Comment: Sorry, added a little more. Hope it helps

Comment: Oh thanks for the link. I added `user = profile;` to signin callback and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Built in providers don't take additional functions like profile , they are for custom providers. : ) https://next-auth.js.org/providers/google